# "git remote -v" shows (fetch) and (push) twice, once for 'github' and once for 'origin' what does that mean?

Tags: git, bash, github, push, git-bash

*Not sure if its the right place for asking this question, I was unable to understand something and googling didn't help.*

I have been referring `git` tutorials, (obviously meaning i'm new to it).

I learnt the command `git remote -v` to check the remote status. Well, all the git tutorial had snapshots like [this](http://15809-presscdn-0-93.pagely.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/MTIyMzA0MjIwMjA3Njc4MDU0.png), showing the result:

```
origin  https://github.com/something/something-else.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/something/something-else.git (push)
```

But when I tried the command I am getting similar result for `origin` as well as `github`. Something like this:

```
github  https://github.com/srujan7/something-something-url.git (fetch)
github  https://github.com/srujan7/something-something-url.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/srujan7/something-something-url.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/srujan7/something-something-url.git (push)
```

**Problem:**

I am not sure what does this `github` and `origin` here means. Why did I get it twice? **(unlike the tutorial)** I am also not sure if did anything wrong, or its perfectly right. Pointing me to some other tutorial explaining this will also do.

*Feel free to suggest edits.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Git supports multiple remotes, so this is a normal enough state.  **Edit**: as [sschuberth answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37742157/1256452), it's *not* quite normal to have the same URL for multiple remotes.  It's not *harmful* but you might as well delete one of them.

#### What is a remote?

A remote is just a name, like `origin` or `upstream` or `github` or even `fred` or `srujan`.

Git stores each such name in a configuration file.  Under that name, Git can then store additional information, such as one or more URLs.  (For a remote to be useful it needs to have at least one URL, stored as its `url` setting.)  For fetching, Git normally needs at least one `fetch` setting per remote as well.

#### When `git remote -v` lists two or more remotes

Most commonly, each of your Git repositories will have just one remote, usually named `origin`.  This is because when `git clone` creates a new repository by copying some existing repository, it records (in the new repository) the URL of the existing repository.  To record this, it creates a remote, and by default, it uses the name `origin` for that remote.

The `git remote add` sub-command adds additional remotes.  You specify a name for the remote and a URL, and Git records the new remote name and sets its main URL to the one you just gave.

After this, `git remote` or `git remote show` will list the two (or more) remotes you have set up.

#### How do I use a remote?

When you run `git fetch` or `git push`, the very next word is normally the name of the remote to fetch from or push to.  For instance, `git fetch origin` fetches from the remote named `origin`.

If you have two remotes, one named fred and one named srujan, you can `git fetch fred` or `git fetch srujan`.  Similarly, you can `git push fred` or `git push srujan`.  These will contact the specified remote, using the URL stored under that remote.

When *fetching* from a remote, your Git will copy their Git's branches, but *rename* them so that they are unique to that particular remote.  For instance, if I fetch from remote `srujan`, and srujan's Git (at the specified URL) has branches `master` and `develop`, I will get *remote-tracking* branches named `srujan/master` and `srujan/develop`.  If I then fetch from remote `fred`, I will get remote-tracking branches like `fred/master` and `fred/develop`.

#### What about `git pull`?

The `git pull` command is meant to be a convenient shorthand for `git fetch` followed by `git merge`.  Like `git fetch`, `git pull` takes a third word, which is the name of the remote.  The main thing `git pull` does with this is hand it off to `git fetch`.

The weird thing about `git pull` is that it also takes branch names.  It uses those in an odd way: `git pull srujan master` means "run `git fetch srujan` first, then run `git merge surjan/master`".

You're usually better off just running `git fetch` yourself, at least at first, because it's possible for *either* the fetch step to fail (if your network connection goes down, for instance) *or* the merge step to fail (if the merge cannot be done automatically).  Until you are very familiar with Git, I believe you are better off knowing precisely *which* step has gone wrong, because you will need to take different actions to fix it, depending on which step failed.

You may also want to rebase rather than merging.  This is, if anything, more complex than merging (although often a better approach too).  You *can* get `git pull` to do a rebase instead of a merge, and in fact you can make this happen automatically, but the details are a little bit complicated, and manually running `git fetch` first, and then `git rebase` second, is *not* complicated at all.

(In short, don't use `git pull` until you are very familiar with fetching, merging, and rebasing, and are ready to allow Git to try to do them all at once.)

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. Seems i'll have to try first with a simple .txt file with one line of content, commit it, push it, branch it, pull it and merge it, MYSELF to understand whatas happening. Seems interesting.

Answer (score 4):

In Git, a "remote" basically just is an alias for a server URL, so you don't have to type the full URL all the time. If you don't explicitly specify a remote name, the default name is `origin`. In your case, you have two remotes, `origin` and `github`, pointing to the same URL (for whatever reason; you probably followed some tutorial steps to create the `github` remote for demonstration purposes). So one of the two is superfluous. As `github` is the non-standards name, I'd simply remote that remote again by typing

```
git remote rm github
```